# What's wrong with my forEach method when a simple For Loop works just fine

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, cycle

So, I have a simple task, given the array: let arr = [true, false, true, false, true];  I need to reverse true to false and visa versa. 
I have managed to do this with a for loop: And it works fine.

Now, I'm trying to do the same with a forEach and I can't figure out why this won't work. So, here's my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === true) arr[i] = false;
    else arr[i] = true;
} // it works

// for some reason, this doesn't
arr2.forEach(el => el === true ? el = false : el = true);
console.log(arr)

//Neither this: 
arr.forEach(el => el === true && el = false || el === false && el = true);
console.log(arr)
```

The map doesn't work either:
Can someone point out my mistake and explain what I am doing wrong? Maybe show other ways to solve it? With filter, reduce or which is more preferrable?
A one-liner solution is highly preferred.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `forEach` will just iterate over the values `el = false` does not change the element in the array - you are just changing the local variable. It's the same as if you had done `let el = arr[i]` in your `for` loop and had used `el` throughout it.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `Array.prototype.map`, because assigning `el` is not like assigning `arr[i]` (it doesn't mutate the array):

```
arr2 = arr2.map(el => el === true ? false : true);
```

Which can be simplified to just:

```
arr2 = arr2.map(el => !el);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to `el`, which is the parameter to your callback. That has no effect whatsoever on the value in the array. The **value** of the array element is copied to `el`, after which there is no link between the array element and the `el` parameter. It's like this:

```js
function example(el) {
  console.log("before", el);
  el = 42;
  console.log("after", el);
}

let a = [1];
console.log("a before", String(a));
example(a[0]);
console.log("a after", String(a));
```

If you want to assign to the array from within a `forEach`, you have to do it by index:

```
arr.forEach((el, index) => el === true ? arr[index] = false : arr[index] = true);
```

*(I strongly recommend **not** abusing the conditional operator that way, but that would be the nearest to what you're trying to do.)*

The more idiomatic thing to do would be to use `map`, and `!` rather than the conditional operator:

```
const newArray = arr.map(el => !el);
```

Comment: I'd personally prefer to use the array passed into the `forEach` callback - `(el, index, array) => array[index] = !el;` Sure, it's the same as `arr` but then the callback is self-contained and doesn't beak if `arr.forEach` is changed to, say, `myElements.forEach`

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I mention to mention it was an option to do that.

Comment: @georg - Thank you. Wow, my brain was really misfiring... :-)

Answer (score 2):

From your code, you're trying to change to *el* but the el variable that pass to callback function by forEach function I think it pass by value not pass by reference. From your question, Let's rewrite by using *map* function instead of *forEach*

```
const listOfBoolen = [false, true, false, true, true]
const newList = listOfBoolen.map(o => !o)
console.log(newList) // [true, false, true, false, false]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `.forEach()` version, a *copy* of the value in the array element is passed to the callback function. Changing that parameter value has no effect on the array element.

You could use `.map()`, but that would create a whole new array:

```
let newarr = arr.map(el => el == true ? false : true);
```

Your original `for` loop is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the array element by index:

```js
let arr = [true, false, true, false, true]
arr.forEach((el, i, a) => el === true ? a[i] = false : a[i] = true);
console.log(arr);
//OR: Simply
//arr.forEach((el, i, a) => a[i] = !el);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not assigning the value to arry. you cam use map() and foreach to do this, like given below

```js
arr = [true, false, true, false, true];
arr =arr.map(val=> this.val=!val);
console.log(arr)

///////////////////////////////////

arr = [true, false, true, false, true];
arr.forEach((val,key)=>arr[key]=!val);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of the parameter supplied in the `forEach()` callback, but not actually updating the array.

1. You need to either modify the original array using `forEach()` by assigning the new value to the index. Comparing the boolean with `false` will invert it as if the value is `false` then `false === false` would be `true` and if it is `true` then `true === false` would be `false`.
2. Use map and invert the values and get a new array from the inverted values. I used the XOR `^` to invert the boolean, but the usual `!boolean` is a better alternative than this.

```js
let arr = [true, false, true, false, true]; 

// Creates a new array and applying xor ^ to inverse the boolean
const inverted = arr.map(el => Boolean(1 ^ el));
console.log(inverted)

// Modifies original array
arr.forEach((el, idx, a) => a[idx] = el === false);
console.log(arr)
```